Spark error when .cache and df.queryExecution.explainString(ExplainMode.fromString(SimpleMode.name))
I have the following error in some of my unit tests on my CI and local sbt (but not in Intellij).
They appeared when I bumped Spark from 3.2.1 to 3.5.1  (and scala 2.12 to 2.13 (and java8 to java17))

[info] - must return the right value *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
[info]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$makeCopy$6(TreeNode.scala:762)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.makeCopy(TreeNode.scala:761)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:818)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.innerChildren$lzycompute(InMemoryRelation.scala:404)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState()" because the return value of "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.session()" is null
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.<init>(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:90)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
[info]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$makeCopy$6(TreeNode.scala:762)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.makeCopy(TreeNode.scala:761)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:818)
[info]   ...

After investigations:

it fails 70/80% of times
remove a .cache make it works at 100%
error occurs just after the cache when I call df.queryExecution.explainString(ExplainMode.fromString(SimpleMode.name))

